# Convert string in a executable function - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have add this function to `system.js` collection of MongoDB to use it in a map/reduce context:

```
{ "_id" : "sum", "value" : "function(x,y) {return x+y};" }
```

As you can see, the `value` of `sum`function is a String; indeed when I try to execute the function in MongoDB shell:

```
db.eval("sum(3,12)")
```

I get an error:

```
 "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Property 'sum' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

How can I convert the string in a executable function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need eval. Run `db.loadServerScripts()` on your mongo shell and then call your function as `sum(3,12);`

btw db.eval() is deprecated since version 3.0 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can I call `db.loadServerScripts()` using java class/method instead of using MongoDB shell?

Comment: I don't know the Java driver that you use, but I assume that it's possible. You should check its reference.